# Keep old class and toggle new class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create collapsible tree. I this my leaf nodes have class="member". The code highlights the path user is on in the tree. The problem is when i am using $(this).toggleClass("xyz"); it is removing my "member" class.
I want to keep both class on leaf node

```
<li class="member xyz">Name</li>
```

[jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/vc64ttu1/8/)

using the member class I have css style that changes bullet images on my original code. so, i need to keep the member class.

Comment: _.removeAttr("class")_ is the problem.. it's clearing all your classes

Comment: if I don't doe removeAttr then the color <li> doesn't get back to normal is I click on other <li>

Comment: You should use `.removeClass("className")` for that.

Comment: Simple: use this instead: _$("li.selected").removeClass("selected");_

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vc64ttu1/9/

Comment: Thanks all - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vc64ttu1/10/)  is exactly the behavior that i s needed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Examine this code:

```
$("li.clickedli").removeAttr("class");
```

This removes the entire class attribute, thus removing all classes.  Just set/clear the specific classes you need/don't need.

Comment: thanks . i replaced it with - $("li.clickedli").removeClass("clickedli"); and now it is working the way I want it.